# how to fill out W4 when i'm getting $1600 extra income a month

Tags: united-states, taxes

Aug 22 was my last day at a job that paid $76,000 / yr. After that that job is supposed to pay me $400 / wk for consulting for $1,600 / month. At the new job (which I started on Aug 26) I'm making $80,000 / yr.

On the W4 (http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf) I filled out there was a section for "additional amount, if any, you want withheld from each paycheck". I'm thinking I could use this section to withhold taxes on the consulting money I'm getting for as long as I'm getting it. It's just not clear to me how much I need to withhold.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi sparkane.  This is off-topic on The Workplace, as jmort253 noted, but I'm going to migrate it over to [money.se] for you.  Good luck.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: It'd be nice if the system migrated previously written comments/answers along with the questions...